# Struct ownership

Tags: rust, ownership

```
struct Haha {
    pub a: u32,
    pub b: Vec<u32>,
}
```

```
let example = Haha {
    a: 32,
    b: vec![1],
}; 
let new_a = example.a;
let new_b = example.b;
```

My understanding is:

1. `new_a` is a copy of `example.a` so `example` still owns `example.a`.
2. `new_b` now owns `example.b` since `example.b` was moved.

Does rust implicitly copy `example.a` because it has `Copy` trait? And since `example.b`, which is a `Vec`, does not implement `Copy` trait, ownership of `example.b` is moved rather than copied?

Comment: Check out this blog post https://medium.com/@bugaevc/understanding-rust-ownership-borrowing-lifetimes-ff9ee9f79a9c
"Fortunately, Rust has the Copy trait. Types that implement it (all the primitive ones do) use copy semantics when assigning, all the other types use move semantics."

Answer (score 6):

Your understanding is correct. `a` is copied while `b` is moved. You can confirm this by trying to access the two fields afterwards.

```
println!("{:?}", example.a);
```

This prints `32`. `example.a` is still accessible because it was copied, not moved.

```
println!("{:?}", example.b);
```

Accessing `example.b` fails to compile with the error message:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `example.b`
  --> src/main.rs:13:22
   |
12 |     let _new_b = example.b;
   |                  --------- value moved here
13 |     println!("{:?}", example.b);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `example.b` has type `std::vec::Vec<u32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Which confirms exactly what you said, that `example.b` was moved because it doesn't implement the `Copy` trait.

Comment: thanks for a quick response! So for rust newbies like me(who might not know vec does not implement copy trait), do we have to rely on the compiler to check ownership since copy is done implcitily?

Comment: @LouisLee you can see in the [API documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) whether a type is `Copy` or not.

Comment: @LouisLee If a variable's size is known at compile time (for example i32), it can be stored in the stack, thus it is fast to copy. If a variable's size it not known at compile time (for example vectors), it will be stored in the heap and a pointer to the memory location in the heap is stored in the stack. Rust doesn't duplicate memory in the heap because it's slow and inefficient. You can assume that if a variable is using the heap, it won't implement the copy trait.

Comment: i have one more question. I thought structs and enums were saved in stack by default unless some fields have to be allocated in the heap. So if i do this
```
struct haha{
    pub a: i32, 
    pub b: inner
}
struct inner{
    pub c: u32
}
```
although I didn't derive copy or clone trait for struct inner, i was expecting struct inner to be stack allocated but the compiler tells me it isn't. So are struct's stored in the heap unless they derive copy trait?

Comment: @LouisLee No, Rust does not automatically decide whether something is allocated on the stack vs the heap. By default things are allocated on the stack. Some structs such as `Vec` are implemented in such a way that they allocate things on the heap. Just making something `Copy` or not does not change whether it's allocated on the stack or heap.